# Linux not sending NDP for routed packets

Tags: networking, linux-networking, ipv6, ndp

I have configured IPv6 networking on three machines A, B, C (B and C are LXD containers running on A). B and C are directly connected only to A. I've assigned addresses `fdef:9062:4cf7:5::2/64` and `fdef:9062:4cf7:5::2/64` respectively on interfaces connecting A to B and C. I've assigned `fdef:9062:4cf7:5::1/64` address on B and `fdef:9062:4cf7:3::1/64` on C. I've added route `fdef:9062:4cf7::1/48 via fdef:9062:4cf7:5::2/64` on B and `fdef:9062:4cf7::1/48 via fdef:9062:4cf7:3::2/64` on C. I have `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1` on all hosts and I don't run `radv`.

Now, I can ping both B and C from host A, but pinging B from C (and vice vera) works only if B and C are in A neighbour cache! As if the kernel forgot to send NDP for routed packets, but not for packets directly sent by `ping`.

Is this normal behavior? I'm confused, because I've expected that IPv6 routing will work in a same way as IPv4 routing.

Comment: You mention that you have enabled `net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1` on all hosts. Have you also enabled `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1`?

Comment: Yes, that was just a typo.

Comment: I'd want to check `ip6tables` has no forwarding policy set to drop or natting set.

Comment: "I've assigned addresses fdef:9062:4cf7:5::2/64 and fdef:9062:4cf7:5::2/64 respectively" I guess the second one is fdef:9062:4cf7:3::2/64

Comment: "I've added route fdef:9062:4cf7::1/48 via fdef:9062:4cf7:5::2/64 on B" I guess it should be "I've added route fdef:9062:4cf7::/48 via fdef:9062:4cf7:5::2 on B"

Comment: …you could just include the routing tables.